# Java and MySQL: duplicate value for 'primary key' exception

Tags: java, mysql

I do some insert in a MySQL DB with a for cycle.

I have a problem with the auto-increment, 'cause after the first insert I obtain an com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.

Here the code:

```
for (int i=0; i<numKeys; i++) {
try {
   stm1 = this.db_connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (Cod, Prop, Field, Value) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
   stm1.setInt(1, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
   stm1.setInt(2, 0);
   stm1.setString(3, aname);  
   stm1.setString(4, avalue);
       stm1.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Cod is an auto-increment-field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a auto incremented field then there is no reason to pass it in as an argument, just don't include it in the Insert statement.

```
stm1 = this.db_connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (Prop, Field, Value) VALUES (?,?,?)");
```

And remove the appropriate setInt method below.

Answer (score 1):

`Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` is a int constants,

If you try adding it multiple time with same primary key it will fail to add

Comment: Well that and the fact its an auto increment field so he really shouldn't be setting its value himself.

Answer (score 0):

If Cod is autoincrement you don't need to insert it. You should try the following code.

```
for (int i=0; i<numKeys; i++) {
try {
   stm1 = this.db_connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO mytable (Prop, Field, Value) VALUES (?,?,?)");
   stm1.setInt(1, 0);
   stm1.setString(2, aname);  
   stm1.setString(3, avalue);
   stm1.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think this would work, you are passing in a different number of paramaters to values in the sql statement.  See my answer below.  To clarify, you need to remove one of the ? in the values part of your sql statement so that there are only 3 of them.

Comment: @JonTaylor yes my mistake! Thnks!